# Explain the sentence in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **HOME COMFORT**
>   It was a lazy Sunday afternoon, the lull before the storm
>   of Monday morning madness of alarm clocks, traffic jams and deadlines. The clock struck three and Rebecca’s elbow still rested on the arm of the tapestry-covered sofa. **With her fingertips she began caressing the rough piping that ran along its seams.** Simultaneously, the toes of her left foot moved back and forth across the edges of the sheepskin rug.
>   (Source: https://www.flo-joe.co.uk/cae/students/tests/read3pr1.htm)

I understand the word-by-word translation of the sentence but it makes no sense to me. I think it somehow related to the sofa which was previously mentioned but I don't understand in which way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sentence sounds fine to me, but maybe the word *piping* is tripping you up. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piping_(sewing)):

> In sewing, **piping** is a type of trim or embellishment consisting of a strip of folded fabric so as to form a "pipe" inserted into a seam to define the edges or style lines of a garment or other textile object.

For example, this off-white sofa has black piping:

[image]

So, if Rebecca was lounging on that sofa, she would be absent-mindedly rubbing her fingertips along one of those black seams.